# Open page from ion-modal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I want to open another page on the model page,
Currently, I am first dismissing the model page then opening another page but that taking time to open another page and
it's a bad user experience.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,AlertController,ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import {FirstPage} from '../first/first.page';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor( private modalCtrl:ModalController,private alertCtrl:AlertController) {}

  async moveToFirst()
  {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
     component: FirstPage
   });

   await modal.present();
   const { data } = await modal.onWillDismiss();
console.log(data);
this.router.navigate(['secondpage']);
  }
}
```

How can I achieve it to open another page from the modal page fast?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is something like **[this](https://ionicframework.com/blog/how-to-navigate-in-ionic-modals-with-ion-nav/)** what you're looking for?

Comment: No I went through this but here navigation happening from modal to  modal where modal is defined into home.module but I need to navigate it to a lazy loaded page which has its own module.ts

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Do you know if the delay is because of the closing modal animation or if it's because the module of the second page is being loaded before the page is pushed? (maybe you can inspect this in the Chrome developer tools).

Comment: Delay is because of closing model animation is slide-out and modal is kind of alert controller, so closing model and opening another page is time taking that client's don't want. It should be quick as regular pushing to new page